# Wrong positive on Enums in ReSharper

Tags: c#, enums, resharper

```
public enum EnumValues
{
    Val1, 
    Val2, 
    Val3 
}

...

public Foo()
{
    var valueList = Enum.GetNames(typeof(EnumValues)).ToList();
    var value = EnumValues.Val1;
    // some userinteraction here with valueList and value...
    ...
    return value;
}
```

Produces Resharper-Warning UnusedMember "Type or member is never used" on Val2 and Val3.

An solution would be to add a file- or line-based ReSharper disable:

```
public enum EnumValues
{
    Val1, 
    // ReSharper disable once UnusedMember.Global
    Val2, 
    // ReSharper disable once UnusedMember.Global
    Val3 
}
```

Any idea how to fix that without the 'disable'-noise?

Comment: You can use the `[UsedImplicitly(ImplicitUseTargetFlags.WithMembers)]` attribute, but the feature works as expected here, it doesn't handle reflection use.

Comment: Does Enum.GetNames really use reflection?

Comment: Yes ([see here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/type.cs,d5cd3cb0c6c2b6c1)), but that's to be expected as you used `typeof`

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
public enum EnumValues
{
    // ReSharper disable UnusedMember.Global
    Val1, 
    Val2, 
    Val3 
    // ReSharper restore UnusedMember.Global
}
```

This should work without problems